# Reduce boilerplate when narrowing down string array type into tuple of string literals

Tags: typescript

I have the same code written twice. Once for the type, and once for the value.
How can I reduce the boilerplate in a way that is easy to understand?

```
type Chart = {
  started: ["count"];
  counting: ["count", "end"];
  ended: ["restart"];
};

const chart: Chart = {
  started: ["count"],
  counting: ["count", "end"],
  ended: ["restart"]
};
```

Note: `as const` almost works, but adds `readonly`, making other types mismatch unless basically all code is written with `readonly`.

Here's a playground with other alternatives for inspiration: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-UaaGg417VhuLWgB4YQ5AA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as const`, as you described, and then use a mapped type modifier to remove `readonly` from all the properties.

```
const chart = {
  started: ["count"],
  counting: ["count", "end"],
  ended: ["restart"]
} as const;

type ChartReadonly = typeof chart;

// you can use a basic generic to help here.
type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly[P in keyof T]: T[P];
};

type Chart = Mutable<ChartReadonly>;

// or without generics
type Chart2 = {
  -readonly[P in keyof ChartReadonly]: ChartReadonly[P];
};

// or all at once:
type Chart3 = {
  -readonly[P in keyof typeof chart]: typeof chart[P];
};
```

Comment: Nice! I like `type Chart = Mutable<typeof chart>` the most. It's like your first alternative with `typeof` inlined. Thanks for the help!